# Add Image on the Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Any one help me. How to add the image on the button? I am using following code for create a button. I want to display the image instead of "refresh". is it possible to do this?
Thanks in advance.

```
<div data-role="button" data-iconpos="right" id="searchResultRefresh" data-icon="refresh"> 
 refresh </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in this document:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html

Custom icons are mentioned at the bottom.
Take one of the existing ui-icon-sth classes and change the offsets to refer to the end of the icons file and then add your icon there if you want to reuse it a lot.

If not - just change the image link in the copied CSS and remove background-position definition.

Comment: Hi..  Thanks... I used the following code display the icon alone. But Still I am getting button with text "<a href="index.html" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext">Delete</a>".

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. It is working fine. I have to use jquery1.4.4.js. Otherwise the button will display with text only. Before I used the jquery1.4.3.js.

Comment: Good to know. Thakns for mentioning.

Comment: +1 for Girija, thanks for noting the bug in 1.4.3, I was wracking my brain and the internet trying to figure out why those images weren't showing up.

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature introduced in 1.4.4 :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not a button, it's a `div` element.

To have button with image, have such HTML:

```
<button type="button"><img src="Refresh.gif" /></button>
```

Comment: In jquery mobile that div is a button.